# Detect keypressing in a textbox and converting user text to a string

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to write something in a TextBox, then I want to press Enter and convert the input into a string.

How do you do this in WinForms?

Comment: Thats not a question, its a requirement. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to be *specific* and not just a list of requirements. Please see [Why is "Can Someone Help Me" not an "actual" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: But the two blocks of code are identical?

Comment: Also, your "requirements" are completely unintelligible. Its not clear at all what you are actually trying to do (let alone this being an actual question). Regardless, please read the linked meta post, it will explain far better than I can in 500 characters.

Comment: I knew that some people will be like this. Thanks Bradley. I asked question, if you don't know how to answer. Please try to answer another question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Steve. I edited now the question.

Comment: @Khoury39 Don't assume what I know. If you were clear, I'm sure I *could* give you the answer. That said, you need to ask a clear question before anyone can help. If you need help figuring out what isn't clear, for starters, this statement " click enter to convert what I write to a string" is utter nonsense. Since right now your question is "how do I do that", its pretty unanswerable.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sorry for not being that clear. I'm portuguese and it's dificult for me asking questions in english.

Comment: Give it another go then (with an edit) :) Downvotes can be undone if you make the question better. Perhaps describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BradleyDotNet I will rewrite the question...

Comment: @Khoury39 you do know that there is http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ , don't you?

Comment: @BradleyDotNet Question rewrited.

Comment: You still have that "convert what I write to a string" nonsense in there. Input to a text box is *already* a `string` (not sure what else it could be, really) so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a folder with what I written posteriorly. That's why I said "convert it to a string".

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to take the text box input and if "enter" is pressed inside that text box create a folder at that location (hopefully the input is a valid path)? If so, thats all very important information for your question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Well, I want to take the text box input **when** enter is pressed. Just that. The folder creation I make it posteriorly.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, input into a `TextBox` is already a `string` and is stored in the `Text` property. So that part is easy.

Triggering off of the "Enter" key is another story however. The easiest way is with the [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Assign something like the following handler to your text box's `PreviewKeyDown` event (either in code-behind or through the designer):

```
void HandleKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string input = (sender as TextBox)?.Text;
        //Your logic
        e.IsInputKey = true; //Don't do standard "Enter" things
    }
}
```

The reason you use `PreviewKeyDown` is that the later events (`KeyDown`, `KeyPress`, `KeyUp`) won't trigger on "Enter" because its not a "InputKey". The linked documentation explains is in fuller detail.

Notes:

- If you want the standard handling of "Enter" to continue, then don't set `IsInputKey` to true.
- The first line of the `if` statement says "Cast the control that raised this event to `TextBox` and get it's `Text` property." You could instead use the TextBox's name, or a number of other things.
- The `?.` is in case the cast fails due to the control not actually *being* a `TextBox` (`input` will be null in that case). This is only valid syntax in C# 6.

Comment: I will try. Thank you for your time helping the new ones.

Comment: @Khoury39 No problem, feel free to comment if you need any clarification. I promise, the only reason users here are so keen on high-quality is we want to create the best content possible, and help you learn along the way!.

Comment: I tryed using your code. The first error I got is in the "?.Text; - it says that the term '.' is a invalid expression. The second one is in the IsInputKey, that don't exist in my Windows.Forms...

Comment: `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  chattextbox = nome.Text;
 }` I tryed this code to get the text from the textbox, now I just need a keypressing detection, right?

Comment: @Khoury39 The syntax will only work under C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015), `IsInputKey` should be there, the documentation I linked is for WinForms. The last part will work, but `TextChanged` won't let you trap the enter key (which the documentation I linked describes).

Answer (score 0):

The text in the textbox would already be a string. You can grab the text value of the textbox by simply grabbing the .Text property.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.